# Jquery event fired twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I m trying to learn Jquery and I m doing some experiments. Here is my markup :

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <p id="success"></p>
    <h1>Break the views</h1><br>
    <img id ="product" src="Tshirt2.jpg">
    <div id="our-prices">
        <span>Price: </span><span id ="price">10</span><span> €</span><br>
        <span>Tax: <span id = "tax">2,3</span><span> €</span><br>
        <span>Total: </span><span id = "total">12,3</span><span> €</span><br>
        <input id ="qty" type="range" value="1" min="0" max="10"></input><br>
        <span>Picked: </span><span id ="qty">1</span><span> product(s):</span><br><br>
        <button id="buy">ADD TO CART</button>
    </div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#success").hide();
    var qty = $("#qty").val();
    console.log(qty);

    $("#buy").click(function(){
        $("#success").fadeIn(500);
        $("#success").text(qty + " products were added to your cart");
        $("#success").fadeOut(500);
    });
});

$("#qty").change(function(){
    var qty = $(this).val();
    var price = qty * 10;
    var tax  = price * 0.23;
    var total = price + tax;

    $("#price").text(price);
    $("#tax").text(tax.toFixed(2));
    $("#total").text(total);
    $("span #qty").text(qty);

    $("#buy").click(function(){
        $("#success").fadeIn(500);
        $("#success").text(qty + " products were added to your cart");
        $("#success").fadeOut(500);
```

The success event (hide / fade) is firing twice if changed event occurs in #qty. On the other hand if I don't declare `var qty` in `document.ready`, this is solved but the initial state of var qty is undefined on page load. Why is this happening? Basically my question is how can I rewrite this in order Variable Qty is available inside the .changed event ?
Thank you

Comment: Where do you close your `change(function() {`?

Comment: If your code really looks like that, it's no suprise the event fires twice, you have the event handler for `#buy` clicking added twice, and even inside another event handler ?

Comment: Not related to question but just for better coding you can use chaining 
$("#success").fadeIn(500).).text(qty + " products were added to your cart")..fadeOut(500); instead of seperately calling $("#sucess")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remarks :

- you have two elements with the id=qty
- you declare the $("#buy").click(function() twice
- to make the var qty avaible on the whole document, you must declare it once and the you can change the value after (but not redeclare)

Run this code snippet to see the result

```html
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The code</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>        
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
            <p id="success">Success</p>
            <h1>Break the views</h1><br>
            <img id ="product" src="Tshirt2.jpg">
        <div id="our-prices">
            <span>Price: </span><span id ="price">10</span><span> €</span><br>
            <span>Tax: <span id = "tax">2,3</span><span> €</span><br>
            <span>Total: </span><span id = "total">12,3</span><span> €</span><br>
            <input id="qty" type="range" value="1" min="0" max="10"/><br>
            <span>Picked: </span><span id="qtySpan">1</span><span> product(s):</span><br><br>
            <button id="buy">ADD TO CART</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    var qty;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#success").hide();
        $("#buy").click(function(){
            qty=$("#qty").val();
            $("#success").fadeIn(500);
            $("#success").text(qty+" products were added to your cart");
            $("#success").fadeOut(500);
        });

        $("#qty").change(function(){
            qty=$("#qty").val();
            var price =qty*10;
            var tax  = price*0.23;
            var total =price +tax;
            $("#price").text(price);
            $("#tax").text(tax.toFixed(2));
            $("#total").text(total);
            $("span#qtySpan").text(qty);
        });
    });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove last buy button event code.

You have bind event when qty change so it will increase the bind when you change the qty so remove buy event from $("#qty").change(function(){ function

```
$("#buy").click(function(){
$("#success").fadeIn(500);
$("#success").text(qty+" products were added to your cart");
$("#success").fadeOut(500);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read up a bit on JavaScript basics and syntax before jumping in to jQuery, as there's a couple of simple mistakes in here.

The immediate problem is that your `$("#qty").change()` function never closes, but also you're calling `$("#buy").click` twice. As a starting point make the following changes...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#success").hide();
    var qty = $("#qty").val();
    console.log(qty);

    $("#buy").click(function(){
        $("#success").fadeIn(500);
        $("#success").text(qty + " products were added to your cart");
        $("#success").fadeOut(500);
    });
});

$("#qty").change(function(){
    var qty = $(this).val();
    var price = qty * 10;
    var tax  = price * 0.23;
    var total = price + tax;

    $("#price").text(price);
    $("#tax").text(tax.toFixed(2));
    $("#total").text(total);
    $("span #qty").text(qty);
    // Removed seconds $("#buy").click listener and closed function
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but there is still a problem. Even if the input range is changes always qty = 1 in the success message.